# Why the order of rows changes in mysql upon update

Tags: mysql

I am displaying the contents of a table on a web page, I execute simply

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME
```

inside my java code

I am also using Ajax to allow user to change the contents of the rows, then without refreshing (thats what Ajax do) display the changes made.

Now the problem is when the changes are reflected the order changes, and it becomes difficult for the user.

Here's a image to explain it graphically
[image: PLease let me know if you cant see the image]

So I wanted to ask that

- why this happens
- How to prevent it

**Note** : I am not showing the primary key on the page, for obvious reasons

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't specify explicit `ORDER BY` - `mysql` (and any other RDBMS) does not guarantee any particular order.

An important note: even having `ORDER BY` doesn't guarantee stable result set though, until you have a unique column (or tuple) that participate in sorting.

So the answer is: add `ORDER BY`

Comment: Oh thank you very much, now I feel like asking silly question.